# Jersey 1.x and Tomcat: how to register a ContainerRequestFilter programmatically, i.e. without web.xml?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-1.0

## My application

In my JAX-RS/Jersey application running in Tomcat, I need to run a filter class that implements `ContainerRequestFilter` before every resource method. The filter determines whether or not the service is available right now<sup>1</sup>. This is done rather simply if I register the filter in web.xml:

**DataResource.java**:

```
package thepackage;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/data")
public class DataResource {

  @GET
  @Produces("application/json")
  public String getData() {
    return "{\"data\": [{\"id\": 1},{\"id\": 2}]}";
  }

}
```

**ServiceAvailabilityFilter.java**:

```
package thepackage;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class ServiceAvailabilityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

  private boolean isServiceAvailable(ContainerRequest request) {
    // Actual logic goes here; for this sample, just flip a coin
    return RANDOM.nextBoolean();
  }

  @Override
  public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
    if (isServiceAvailable(request)) {
      return request;
    } else {
      throw new WebApplicationException(
          Response.serverError().type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
              .entity("{\"error\":\"Service not available\"}").build()
      );
    }
  }

}
```

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>io.github.garysheppardjr.jersey1xfiltertest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
      <param-value>io.github.garysheppardjr.jersey1xfiltertest.ServiceAvailabilityFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

## My question

However, I don't want to declare the `ServiceAvailabilityFilter` in XML. I want to register it in Java code. How would I do that?

## Things I would rather not do

- Declare the filter in web.xml. *Why not? If I deliver this application as on-premises software, I want to make sure someone can't disable my filter by editing web.xml.*
- Check for service availability in the `DataResource` class. *Why not? I don't want to write and maintain new code in all of my resource classes. This is one thing that filters can avoid.*
- Change from Jersey 1.x to Jersey 2.x. *Why not? I have dependencies and deadlines that will make moving to Jersey 2.x very difficult.*

---

<sup>1</sup> Why might the service be unavailable, you might ask? It doesn't matter. Use your imagination. That logic is not relevant to this question, so I have replaced it with `Random.nextBoolean()`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `<servlet>` element from web.xml (or even delete web.xml altogether if that's all you have in it and you're using at least Servlet API 3.0). To take the place of the `<servlet>` element, create a class that extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`. In the case of this question, it might be easiest to extend `com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig`. Annotate your new class with `javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath`. Do your `<init-param>` settings in the constructor of this class.

**DataResource.java**: no change.

**ServiceAvailabilityFilter.java**: no change.

**MyApplication.java** (or whatever you want to call it):

```
package thepackage;

import com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends PackagesResourceConfig {

  public MyApplication() {
    // "com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages" init-param
    super(DataResource.class.getPackageName());
    // "com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters" init-param
    getContainerRequestFilters().add(ServiceAvailabilityFilter.class);
  }

}
```

**web.xml**: delete at least the `<servlet>` element, or you can delete the file altogether.